# OperationalError: stack depth limit exceeded

Tags: database, postgresql, odoo

Working with openerp 6.1, I want to make a trigger to create two phone calls with dates different from the date in the inserted row (one after 6 months and one after one year).

I created this function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION create_first_phonecall()
  RETURNS trigger AS
$BODY$
BEGIN
select * from crm_phonecall where id= (select max(id) from crm_phonecall);
   insert into crm_phonecall (name,date,state,active,user_id,x_contractnumber,x_instdate)
values('Hany', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,'open',true,16,123456789999,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);
return null;
END;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
```

Then I created the following trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER create_first_phonecall
    AFTER insert ON crm_phonecall
    EXECUTE PROCEDURE create_first_phonecall();
```

But when i try to insert a phone call i get the following error:

```
Client Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\OpenERP\Server\server\openerp\addons\web\common\http.py", line 180, in dispatch
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\OpenERP\Server\server\openerp\addons\web\controllers\main.py", line 970, in create
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\OpenERP\Server\server\openerp\addons\web\common\openerplib\main.py", line 250, in proxy
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\OpenERP\Server\server\openerp\addons\web\common\openerplib\main.py", line 117, in proxy
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\OpenERP\Server\server\openerp\addons\web\common\http.py", line 608, in send


Server Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\OpenERP\Server\server\openerp\addons\web\common\http.py", line 593, in send
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\OpenERP\Server\server\.\openerp\netsvc.py", line 360, in dispatch_rpc
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\OpenERP\Server\server\.\openerp\service\web_services.py", line 586, in dispatch
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\OpenERP\Server\server\.\openerp\osv\osv.py", line 167, in execute_kw
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\OpenERP\Server\server\.\openerp\osv\osv.py", line 121, in wrapper
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\OpenERP\Server\server\.\openerp\osv\osv.py", line 176, in execute
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\OpenERP\Server\server\.\openerp\osv\osv.py", line 164, in execute_cr
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\OpenERP\Server\server\.\openerp\osv\orm.py", line 4194, in create
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\OpenERP\Server\server\.\openerp\sql_db.py", line 152, in wrapper
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\OpenERP\Server\server\.\openerp\sql_db.py", line 212, in execute
OperationalError: stack depth limit exceeded
HINT:  Increase the configuration parameter "max_stack_depth", after ensuring the platform's stack depth limit is adequate.
CONTEXT:  SQL statement "SELECT 1 FROM ONLY "public"."res_users" x WHERE "id" OPERATOR(pg_catalog.=) $1 FOR SHARE OF x"
SQL statement "INSERT INTO crm_phonecall (name,date,state,active,user_id,x_contractnumber,x_instdate) values('Hany', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,'open',true,16,123456789999,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)"
PL/pgSQL function "create_first_phonecall" line 3 at SQL statement
SQL statement "INSERT INTO crm_phonecall (name,date,state,active,user_id,x_contractnumber,x_instdate) values('Hany', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,'open',true,16,123456789999,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)"
PL/pgSQL function "create_first_phonecall" line 3 at SQL statement
SQL statement "INSERT INTO crm_phonecall (name,date,state,active,user_id,x_contractnumber,x_instdate) values('Hany', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,'open',true,16,123456789999,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)"
...
```

(Many more of the same message from Postgres.)

Can anyone help me with that?

Comment: I would need the table definition (`\d tbl` in psql). Also, your current trigger does not make sense. It would raise an exception: `SELECT` without target is not possible in plpgsql. Please post your actual working trigger function. Also, as *always* your version of Postgres.

Comment: sorry the actual function code is:  CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION create_first_phonecall()
  RETURNS trigger AS
$BODY$
BEGIN
   insert into crm_phonecall (name,date,state,active,user_id,x_contractnumber,x_instdate)
values('Hany', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,'open',true,16,123456789999,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);
return null;
END;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'       i add the select statement to get the data from the inserted row becuase i need it in the rows that i need to insert

Comment: Please, use `edit` left under your question to update essential information in the question. (But what you posted in the comment still isn't valid code: `SELECT` without target is not allowed in plpgsql.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`RETURN NULL` does not cancel the operation in an `AFTER` trigger. The trigger inserts a new row, which triggers the next `INSERT` ... which results in an endless loop.
Thus the **stack overflow** - yes, you have come to the right site. ;)

You need a "break condition": something to let Postgres see the difference between automatically added and initially inserted rows. (My first draft with a `BEFORE` alone trigger did not solve this.) Could be anything that's clearly defined. Like a boolean flag:

```
ALTER TABLE crm_phonecall ADD COLUMN auto_insert bool;
```

Set the flag to `TRUE` in automatically inserted rows and break for such rows:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION create_first_phonecall()
  RETURNS trigger AS
$func$
BEGIN

-- Removed incoherent code

IF NEW.auto_insert THEN
   -- do nothing
ELSE
   INSERT INTO crm_phonecall
         (name,    ..., auto_insert)
   VALUES('Hany',  ..., TRUE );        -- automatically inserted row
END IF;

RETURN NULL;

END
$func$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

And make the trigger `BEFORE`, not `AFTER`:

```
CREATE TRIGGER create_first_phonecall
BEFORE INSERT ON crm_phonecall
EXECUTE PROCEDURE create_first_phonecall();
```

#### Alternative: `RULE`

The alternative would be a [**`RULE`**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-createrule.html). Typically, triggers are simpler to handle, but a `RULE` could avoid the endless loop, too.

Comment: after i do this i get that error:            OperationalError: record "new" is not assigned yet
DETAIL:  The tuple structure of a not-yet-assigned record is indeterminate.
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function "create_first_phonecall" line 4 at IF

Comment: @hany: Trigger must be BEFORE.

Comment: i do the insert with event after but the problem now that i want to get values from the row inserted before the trigger fired in the table crm_phonecall. how can i do this ?

Comment: i want to store the whole result from the query witch is one row with different datatypes in one variable:    DECLARE
 result integer[];
BEGIN

 select * into result{''} from crm_phonecall  where id=(select max(id) from crm_phonecall);   can anyone help me??

Comment: @hany: I repeat: essential details must go *into the question*. Comments are not the place. Edit it to make it coherent. Or start a new question for a new question.

Comment: Thanks @Erwin Brandstetter